# btrfs balancing of data raid 1 to data raid 2

Tags: hard-drive, raid, btrfs

I have two drives that it setup with btrfs. Originally I had created a 
data,RAID1
metadata,RAID1

Then I ran out of space so I've tried to go back to data,RAID0 by running this command:

> btrfs fi balance start -dconvert=raid0 /mnt/btrfs_root

The original configuration looked like this:

> Overall:
>       Device size:         1.82TiB
>       Device allocated:        1.82TiB
>       Device unallocated:          2.00GiB
>       Device missing:            0.00B
>       Used:            1.60TiB
>       Free (estimated):      108.81GiB  (min: 108.81GiB)
>       Data ratio:                 2.00
>       Metadata ratio:             2.00
>       Global reserve:        432.00MiB  (used: 0.00B)
>
> Data,RAID1: Size:928.50GiB, Used:820.69GiB    /dev/sdc     928.50GiB
>   /dev/sdd   928.50GiB
>
> Metadata,RAID1: Size:2.00GiB, Used:1.23GiB    /dev/sdc       2.00GiB
>   /dev/sdd     2.00GiB
>
> System,RAID1: Size:8.00MiB, Used:144.00KiB    /dev/sdc       8.00MiB
>   /dev/sdd     8.00MiB
>
> Unallocated:    /dev/sdc     1.00GiB    /dev/sdd     1.00GiB

After running the balance operation I get:

> Overall:
>       Device size:         1.82TiB
>       Device allocated:        1.82TiB
>       Device unallocated:          4.00GiB
>       Device missing:            0.00B
>       Used:          823.08GiB
>       Free (estimated):        1.01TiB  (min: 1.01TiB)
>       Data ratio:                 1.00
>       Metadata ratio:             2.00
>       Global reserve:        416.00MiB  (used: 0.00B)
>
> Data,RAID0: Size:1.81TiB, Used:820.67GiB    /dev/sdc   926.50GiB
>   /dev/sdd   926.50GiB
>
> Data,RAID1: Size:1.00GiB, Used:2.00MiB    /dev/sdc       1.00GiB
>   /dev/sdd     1.00GiB
>
> Metadata,RAID1: Size:2.00GiB, Used:1.21GiB    /dev/sdc       2.00GiB
>   /dev/sdd     2.00GiB
>
> System,RAID1: Size:8.00MiB, Used:160.00KiB    /dev/sdc       8.00MiB
>   /dev/sdd     8.00MiB
>
> Unallocated:    /dev/sdc     2.00GiB    /dev/sdd     2.00GiB

There are now two different Data RAID levels even though it says that my data is at a ratio of 1.00
Additionally it looks like the second data,RAID1 array is 1GB in size.
How do I fix this and just get my data back to a raid0 ?
Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to worry. It is an annoying bug of btrfs-progs that it shows a small previos raid part. You can ignore it. Your dat is in raid0. See that only 2MB is used on raid1? It will not increase.

Comment: Thanks. I did end up running balance again and it went away.